# ng-selected is not working with ng-model in select box - Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-select

While ng-model is used in select box and ng-selected is also used in options with some condition that time ng-selected is not working.

If I will remove ng-model than ng-selected is working, but if i will remove ng-model than how I should get the value of select box in controller.

Please help !

Here is my code...

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-change="accessModeSelected()">
     <option ng-selected="mode.status == '1'"  ng-repeat="mode in storageResult.accessMode" ng-value="mode.name" name="accessMode{{$index}}" id="accessMode">
           {{mode.name}}
     </option>
</select>
```

AngularJS:

```
$scope.storageResult   = {
           "storageAccount":"Enable", 
           "user": "sdcard",
           "pass": "sdcard",
           "wifiIP": "0",
           "ipAddr": "0",
           "accessMode": [
                {"name": "Local Storage","status": "0"},
                {"name":"WiFi Storage", "status": "1"},
                {"name":"Internet Storage", "status": "0"}
            ]
         }
```

Comment: have you tried using ng-options instead of ng-repeat? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: yup ! I tried. but ng-option is also not working.

Comment: The same code I sent, once I tried it in plunkr. That is working in plunkr but not in my application. I don't know where my app is stucking.

Comment: @PiyaModi Please share your plunkr

Comment: there seems to be a problem with ng-value directive. if you change the ng-value="mode.name" to value="{{mode.name}}" it works fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `ng-options` and `ng-init`(for setting default value) instead of `ng-repeat`.

`ng-options` is specifically for `select`

```
<select class="form-control" ng-init="statusselect='WiFi Storage'" ng-model="statusselect" ng-options="mode.name as mode.name for mode in storageResult.accessMode">

</select> Selected Value : {{statusselect}}
```

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/LkLask7y/10/)**

Edit: Using `ng-repeat`

I would prefer `ng-options`,but if you want to use `ng-selected` with `ng-repeat` you'll need provide a default selected value to `ng-model` from your `controller`

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="statusselect">
     <option ng-selected="{{mode.name == statusselect}}" ng-repeat="mode in storageResult.accessMode" value="{{mode.name}}" name="accessMode{{$index}}" id="accessMode">
           {{mode.name}}
     </option>
</select> Selected Value : {{statusselect}}
```

Inside Controller

```
$scope.storageResult  = {
           "storageAccount":"Enable", 
           "user": "sdcard",
           "pass": "sdcard",
           "wifiIP": "0",
           "ipAddr": "0",
           "accessMode": [
                {"name": "Local Storage","status": "0"},
                {"name":"WiFi Storage", "status": "1"},
                {"name":"Internet Storage", "status": "0"}
            ]
         }
   $scope.statusselect = $scope.storageResult["accessMode"][1]["name"];
```

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/LkLask7y/9/)**

Comment: Hi Nishant ! Thanks for answer... but if I will select another option that time I want that name as a input. Here we will get only status. so based on that i can't update my db which mode is enable. In short I want mode name in ng-model

Comment: @PiyaModi I have updated my answer. Now mode name shall be stored in ng-model. The "Selected Value:" besides the select gives you the value that is stored in ng-model.

Comment: @PiyaModi By "In short I want mode name in ng-model"

Do you mean that you want something like this `ng-model="mode.name"`

Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/LkLask7y/11/) what you want?

Comment: Hi Nishant ! Yes.. I want that only... But It s working now with your updated FIDDLE... Thanks for your help... :)

Answer (score 2):

Use ng-options instead of ng-repeat

```
<select ng-model="status"  ng-options="mode.status as mode.name for mode in storageResult.accessMode">
```

and In controller

```
app.controller("dobController", ["$scope", "$http",
  function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.storageResult = {
      "storageAccount": "Enable",
      "user": "sdcard",
      "pass": "sdcard",
      "wifiIP": "0",
      "ipAddr": "0",
      "accessMode": [{
        "name": "Local Storage",
        "status": "0"
      }, {
        "name": "WiFi Storage",
        "status": "1"
      }, {
        "name": "Internet Storage",
        "status": "0"
      }]
    };
    $scope.status = '1';

  }
]);
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/Dn6UtZ2AVhIkZowmH79Y?p=preview)**

Comment: Hi Sajeetharan ! Thanks for answer... but if I will select another option that time I want that name as an input. Here we will get only status. so based on that i can't update my db, which mode is enable. In short I want mode name in ng-model

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are many ways to answer this question and a lot of answers have been provided,but based on OP's question on how to send '`mode.name`' into `ng-model` I've explained below using `ng-options`.

In your JS

```
var app = angular.module('todoApp', []);

    app.controller("dobController", ["$scope", "$http",
        function($scope, $http) {


            $scope.storageResult = {
                "storageAccount": "Enable",
                "user": "sdcard",
                "pass": "sdcard",
                "wifiIP": "0",
                "ipAddr": "0",
                "accessMode": [{
                    "name": "Local Storage",
                    "status": "0"
                }, {
                    "name": "WiFi Storage",
                    "status": "1"
                }, {
                    "name": "Internet Storage",
                    "status": "0"
                }]
            };
            $scope.status = $scope.storageResult.accessMode[0].name;
            $scope.selectedItem = '';

        }
    ]);
```

In your HTML to bind mode name to ng-model follow this.

```
<select ng-model="status"  ng-options="mode.name as mode.name for mode in storageResult.accessMode">
```

To bind entire object you can try below syntax

```
<select ng-model="status"  ng-options="mode as mode.name for mode in storageResult.accessMode">
```

For this make small change in your JS `$scope.status` like

```
$scope.status = $scope.storageResult.accessMode[0];
```

Here is a [DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/3tuYdenSyS0aXOZqCUeY?p=preview) plunker